# ERROR in Error: Method not implemented in Angular Application

Tags: angular

Today when opened WebStorm and tried to run my application, I got this error. Yesterday It was working fine and I don't know how to fix this. Help please!
I saw some topics like mine one, but they all used to deal with cookies, but I don't have any methods including cookies methods(

```
ERROR in Error: Method not implemented.
    at AstTranslator.visitQuote (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/expression.js:225:19)
    at Quote.visit (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7710:28)
    at AstTranslator.translate (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/expression.js:73:24)
    at Object.astToTypescript (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/expression.js:50:27)
    at TcbExpressionTranslator.translate (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:1212:33)
    at tcbExpression (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:1200:27)
    at processAttribute (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:1474:24)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at tcbGetDirectiveInputs (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:1424:19)
    at TcbDirectiveOp.execute (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:342:26)
    at Scope.executeOp (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:975:26)
    at Scope.render (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:888:22)
    at TcbTemplateBodyOp.execute (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:290:54)
    at Scope.executeOp (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:975:26)
    at Scope.render (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:888:22)
    at TcbTemplateBodyOp.execute (/Users/itssmal/Desktop/babybedding/admin/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/typecheck/src/type_check_block.js:290:54)
```

Comment: This just happened to me @Oleksandr  did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I deleted package-lock.json file and rerun npm install. Now it works!

Comment: This problem appears to be caused by malformed binding. Binding a string that is misinterpreted as a property or binding a property when a string is intended.

Answer (score 6):

This error can be caused by missing curly brackets in expression

Eg: `<div class="overlay" [ngClass]="hidden:!showDarkOverlay"> </div>`

The correctly formed expression is:

```
<div class="overlay" [ngClass]="{'hidden':!showDarkOverlay}"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I had something like this in my template:

```
<img [src]="https://www.example.com/{{blah}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before with *finalize()* operator. The error says "Function not implemented" . This was caused by mistakenly clicking on

> Add missing function declaration 'finalize'

instead of

> Add import from 'rxjs/operators'

in the Quick fix menu. so a new function was declared automatically without me noticing it :

```
function finalize(arg0: () => boolean): import("rxjs").OperatorFunction<Object, unknown> {
  throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
}
```